# How to remove empty parameters in querystring asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, query-string

So, I have a method that accepts a string and an object, the object has values that MVC translates into querystring parameters, my question is where and how can I get rid of the parameters that are empty so my url is cleaner.

Form:

```
  @using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Get, 
    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "form2" }))

   //Should I do a check in here for null values before getting the request?
```

Routing Link:

```
     routes.MapRoute
        (
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {controller = "Home", action =        "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Class:

```
class formModel{

 public string name {get;set;}
 public int? age {get;set;}
 public Guid? jobId{get;set;}
 public string Fullname {get;set;}

 }
```

Object properties:

```
     formModel{
                  name: "Mike",
                  age: 29,
                  jobId: null,
                  Fullname: ""
              }
```

Controller action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string sortByText, SearchFormModel formModel)
    {
        var model = new SomeViewModel();
        model.FormModel = formModel;
        //etc

        return View(model);
    }
```

Url:

example: http://www.domain.com/mycontroller?name=Mike&age=29&jobId=&Fullname=&Find=Find

How can I get rid of jobId and Fullname and Find?

Comment: One possibility is to make it nullable and not pass it. Another is to pass a dummy value like 0.

Comment: I am looking into the routing of Global.asax now to see if I can do something there.

Comment: It's not so much in the route as your Action Methods params. Accept a nullable id, or make id optional by defaulting it to 0.

Comment: Is it possible to pass an object in a Get request?

Comment: Yup, it works using an object, but I just want to get rid of the extra parameters that the user did not input in the search.

Comment: @DaveA I already have those values inside the object as nullable.

Comment: I don't see any `date` or `find` in your form model. Do you mean  `jobId` and `Fullname` ?

Comment: I just edited to Fullname, the Find I am not sure how that gets in the url maybe because I passed in an object instead of a string.

Comment: @Cocre8or, if the params are nullable, id say youre done. what am i missing?

Comment: I dont want the user to see 'jobId=&' or 'Fullname=&', after they search to get to the page. so I want to truncate the querstring to only have the keys with values.

Comment: just leave them out...

Comment: @Dave A Yeah, how do I get to the querystring to strip those out.

Comment: try leaving those params out of your populated model. right now you assign Job ID to Null, I suggest not even listing or assigning it.

Comment: I think there is one piece missing.. Are you creating an ActionLink? How you generate the link? can you post the part where you create the link?

Comment: I saw that you updated your question but you didn't show how you generate the link...

Comment: The link is generated by the the mvc routing engine, so on the form, I have the get method, then the engine routes to the action method the data. the sequence controller/action/id optional

Comment: Something not fits, the route redirect to index with id parameter, but in your question you are showing that the index action gets two parameters...

Comment: That's the default route only, I am using a different controller, MVC automatically routes querystrings based on name of each input parameter sent from a FORM, the formModel properties must match the input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up filtering the form data with client-side javascript instead which avoids any unnecessary or empty query parameters.